# If an iOS app isn't made with Interface Builder, is it less likely to be negatively affected by updates to the operating system?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, updates

For example, if you do it all programmatically, are you less likely to run into trouble?

Comment: It has no impact, elements created with the interface builder will work the same way they do. The Interface builder is a tool to help you design interfaces more easily. Most of what it does is just routine work that if done programmatically would just be boilerplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are designing UI with code (not using Xib/Stotyboard) this will be good when you create UI dynamically  so then you need not to spend more time on changes. what ever we use for development (Code/Xib/Storyboard) nothing will be changed in performance. As per user/developer comfort we will go for it. Suppose there are lot of UI need to be displayed few at the time viewdidload and rest after some button action then usually at the initially stage itself Xib and Story board will load all of them and hides un wanted and as per actions it will show the hidden UI. i feel coding is better for me.